# Why is a matrix $M$ diagonalizable, if $M+M^T=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We proved for a matrix $M\in Mat(n,\mathbb{C})$ that $M_{ab}=-M_{ba}$, i.e. we have $M+M^T=0$. This implies that $M$ is diagonalizable.
Can you explain why this is true?

Comment: my first thought is that fact that if the summation of transpose and original M is square and has additive inverses on opposite sides of the diagonal as well as 0 in the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, that's right. We also have proved that the first row and the first column is zero. But how does this help to prove that the matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: it's what came to mind after learning diagonalizeable means similar to a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @Danimark's answer let us look at the matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0&a&b \\ -a &0 &a \\ -b&-a&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We clearly have $M^T=-M$. We can easily compute the characteristic polynomial of $M$ which is $\chi_M=X^3+(2a^2+b^2)X$.

Let us now choose to take $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=i$, such that $\chi_M=X^3$. Then $M$ has a unique eigenvalue, which is $0$. Consequently $M$ is not diagonalizable otherwise it would be similar to the matrix $(0)$.

The result is however true if you replace $M^T$ by $M^*$.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that $M\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, then you use that $M = -M^T$, then $MM^T = M^TM = -M^2$, so by the spectral theorem for normal operators, $M$ is diagonalizable. Similar argument if it's $M^*$, but I think as stated this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: $M$ is complex though, so shouldn't the adjoint be $M^*$?

Comment: no, the matrix is only transposed and complex. Thus I do not see why this is true. I always come to the conclusion that this is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm not so sure that this is true, complex symmetric matrices aren't automatically diagonalizable so I'm skeptical now, unless there was a typo.